# Center list item of unordered list

Tags: html, css

Im trying to build a family tree using `ul` and `li` HTML elements. The code is available [here](http://thecodeplayer.com/experiment/css3-family-tree/2). It uses psedo elements to "draw" the connectors. However The problem is that in case the name of a specific person is too long the styling is bit off as seen in below:

[image]

I am trying to center the vertical connector so that it is in the center of the horizontal connector between 2 parents. Any help will be greatly appreciated. [codepen here](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/ONwEvv)

This is the piece of css that is making the vertical connectors:

```
.tree li:last-child::before{
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateX(1px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(1px);
    transform: translateX(1px);

    -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: -12px; left: 50%;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 0; height: 32px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.tree li a{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
    font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: white;

    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li a+a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.tree li a+a::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    top: 50%; left: -21px; 
    width: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is some kind of a "hack" that adds an invisible node to the tree:

```
<a href="#">Parent</a>
<a href="#">Very long parent name Parent</a>
<a href="#" style="visibility:hidden;">Parent</a> <!-- ugly hack that works -->
```

It center the top row by adding an invisible leaf with the same width as the left leaf (`Parent`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the vertical bars should maybe come from the anchor pseudoclass— not from the unordered list. There's a cool "center anything" technique that I think applies to your problem. Here's a little snippet I added:

```
.tree li a+a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 21px;
  z-index: -1;      
}
```

The `left: 50%; translateX(-50%)` rules handle the centering bit and require only a relatively positioned parent to work, which you already have. I took a screenshot of how it would look applied to an anchor containing a long name.

[image]